# Deserialize JSON object name-value pairs as elements of an array

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to convert following string to an object,

```
{   
    "base":"TRY",
    "date":"2017-01-06",
    "rates":{
       "EUR":0.37679,
       "USD":0.51059,
       "BRL":0.88513,
       "CAD":0.36651,
       ...
    }
}
```

I know, if I create an object containing all rates as `Double` attribute, I will be able to convert that object into an object. But I want rates to be in an array like below. How can I create convertedJsonObjectArrayList. Thanks in advance.

```
List<Rate> rates = convertedJsonObjectArrayList;

class Rate{
    String name; //EUR
    Double value; //0.37679

}
```

Comment: you mean the array is like outside the object?

Comment: you might use an approach like this: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/ since you're trying to convert a json map into a ordinary amount of properties in the java side.

Comment: thank you sombriks I will try that

Comment: I updated question, I need to create convertedJsonObjectArrayList with jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get fancy and write a [custom deserializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers).

However, if you don't mind being a bit more quick-and-dirty, you can just deserialize to a Map, and convert to your preferred structure explicitly:

```
    String ratesAsJson = "{ \"EUR\" : 0.2, \"USD\":1.0 }";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<Map<String, Double>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, Double>>() {};

    Map<String, Double> map = objectMapper.readValue(ratesAsJson, typeRef);
    List<Rate> list = map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new Rate(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(I've assumed a 2-arg constructor on the `Rate` class).

If you write a custom deserializer, it will have very similar code to the above within it.

I've used a stream and `map()`. You could use a `for` loop, but hey, it's 2017!

Answer (score 3):

This assumes that you're guaranteed to have content within the JSON object associated to the name `"rates"` that will be parseable as a `List`.

Define a custom deserializer to consume the name-value tokens as pairs

```
class RatesJsonObjectToArray extends JsonDeserializer<List<Rate>> {
    @Override
    public List<Rate> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        List<Rate> rates = new ArrayList<>();
        // consume two tokens at a time, a name and a value
        for (;;) {
            String name = p.nextFieldName();
            if (name == null) {
                break; // no more input
            }
            JsonToken doubleValueToken = p.nextValue();
            if (doubleValueToken != JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT) { // there's also VALUE_NUMBER_INT for more flexibility
                throw new JsonParseException("Expected a numeric value.");
            }
            double value = p.getDoubleValue();
            rates.add(new Rate(name, value));
        }
        return rates;
    }
}
```

Then annotate your `rates` field/setter with this `JsonDeserializer`

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonDeserialize(using = RatesJsonObjectToArray.class)
private List<Rate> rates;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the currency object(json) into an array(java) You can not use serialization(gson/jaxb) you would need to parse (JsonParser) json and make the conversion yourself

Comment: I know, I wonder if there is a automized way, may be a for loop without if case

Comment: I think not because you would need an annotation in the de/serialization classes that would take the origin json object and convert it into an array of a new class (Currency).

Comment: Probably. I have not read it. But to the best of my knowledge, unless somebody else can point out that kind of annotation, you are stuck with something like I wrote or the other option. Choose what helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution;

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
CurrencyServiceResponse currencyResp = 
    mapper.readValue(jsonStr,new TypeReference<CurrencyServiceResponse>(){});

currencyResp.setRates(new ArrayList<>());
for(Map.Entry<String,Double> entry: currencyResp.getRateMap().entrySet()){
            currencyResp.getRates().add(
                new CurrencyServiceResponse.Rate(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));
        }
```

And class for conversion

```
public class CurrencyServiceResponse {

    @JsonProperty("base")
    private String base;

    @JsonProperty("date")
    private Date date;

    @JsonProperty("rates")
    private Map<String,Double> rateMap;

    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Rate> rates;

    //getters&setters

    public static class Rate{

        private String name;
        private Double value;

        public Rate(String name, Double value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        //getters&setters
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use GSON library. It's the **Google JSON library**.

```
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement root = jp.parse(YOUR_DATA);
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
```

And in your case to **access to the EUR rate** you can use :

```
Double rate_eur = rootobj.get("rates").getAsJsonObject().get("EUR").getAsDouble();
```

Don't forget to **import classes** :

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
```

And **dependencies** :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

for maven for example.

Comment: What does this have to do with the array/list they want? They're not asking how to get the rates as doubles.

Comment: I asked for jackson but thanks again, and Stroirios is right